# Cannot load jxls transformer

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi, classpath, jxls

What's wrong with my project. I've imported all the dependencies but it still outputs error :

[Output errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1Jrx.png)

Here are the list dependencies I imported :
[Dependancies package image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duBDO.png)

And here is my test code :

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package brouillon;

import controllers.RetardJpaController;
import entites.Retard;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import org.jxls.common.Context;
import org.jxls.util.JxlsHelper;

/**
 *
 * @author Vals
 */
public class Brouillon {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO code application logic here
        RetardJpaController ctr = new RetardJpaController(Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("BrouillonPU"));
        List<Retard> liste = ctr.findRetardEntities();
        try(InputStream is = Brouillon.class.getResourceAsStream("ressources/object_collection_template.xls")) {
            try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("object_collection_output.xls")) {
                Context context = new Context();
                context.putVar("retards", liste);
                //JxlsHelper.getInstance().processTemplate(is, os, context);
                JxlsHelper jh = JxlsHelper.getInstance();
                jh.processTemplate(is, os, context);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post the errors as text in the question, rather than as a link to a screenshot of text.

Comment: Searching for that error finds http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html pretty quickly, too...

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load XLS transformer. Please make sure a Transformer implementation is in classpath
 at org.jxls.util.JxlsHelper.createTransformer(JxlsHelper.java:189) at org.jxls.util.JxlsHelper.createTransformer(JxlsHelper.java:189)
 at org.jxls.util.JxlsHelper.processTemplate(JxlsHelper.java:88)
 at brouillon.Brouillon.main(Brouillon.java:39)`

Comment: No, please don't post it as a comment. *Edit the question* to include it there instead of the link.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This doesn't look right to me:

```
    try(InputStream is = Brouillon.class.getResourceAsStream("ressources/object_collection_template.xls")) {
```

Note the misspelling: `"ressources"`.  That's enough to do in the lookup.  Try taking out that second 's' and see if it works.

It might be worse than that.  If resources is a code source, then its contents will be in the CLASSPATH, but the folder itself won't be.  It that case you'd only need the file name.

Try looking at the CLASSPATH you use at runtime and see what's in it.  That'll make it clear.

"I've imported all the dependencies" - this is your biggest problem.  Most beginners and inexperienced programmers fall prey to that attitude of "I've done everything right - why is the computer persecuting me?"  You'll get further faster if you adopt an attitude that begins and ends with "What have I done wrong?" and ruthlessly checks for mistakes by you.

Comment: I moved my template in the same package of the main class and tried this :
 ` try(InputStream is = Brouillon.class.getResourceAsStream("object_collection_template.xls")) { ` 
But didn't work

Comment: Didn't work?  What exception did you get?  Is the InputStream null or not?  Same package as the main class?  Does that mean your main class is not in a package?   More non-information from you. Voting to close.

Comment: the same error :
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load XLS transformer. Please make sure a Transformer implementation is in classpath
 at org.jxls.util.JxlsHelper.createTransformer(JxlsHelper.java:189) at org.jxls.util.JxlsHelper.createTransformer(JxlsHelper.java:189)
 at org.jxls.util.JxlsHelper.processTemplate(JxlsHelper.java:88)
 at brouillon.Brouillon.main(Brouillon.java:39)
Java Result: 1 `

Comment: Which line is #39 in your main class?

Comment: `jh.processTemplate(is, os, context);`

Comment: Google found this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jxls/4LYywN6h7xw

Comment: Believe the JVM - if it says there is no implementation of Transformer in your CLASSPATH, then it's not.  Find one and put it there.

Comment: I left JXLS. now I'm using Apache POI. it works

Comment: There actually more than likely is a Transformer implementation. This is a problem with the exception handling of JXLS, not java. Understanding the problem or actually digging into the exception would have easily shown that. -1 for hasty and inaccurate conclusion. I answered this question on a duplicate since this one was closed.